# Bridge pattern different implementation by type

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

I searched examples for bridge pattern and the following example explains design pattern very well but i have one question about this example.What should i do for example if manual gear handleGear method differs for Car and Truck or auto gear handleGear implementation differs for Car or Truck? Could you please provide example code for this situation?

```
/* Implementor interface*/
interface Gear{
    void handleGear();
}

/* Concrete Implementor - 1 */
class ManualGear implements Gear{
    public void handleGear(){
        System.out.println("Manual gear");
    }
}
/* Concrete Implementor - 2 */
class AutoGear implements Gear{
    public void handleGear(){
        System.out.println("Auto gear");
    }
}
/* Abstraction (abstract class) */
abstract class Vehicle {
    Gear gear;
    public Vehicle(Gear gear){
        this.gear = gear;
    }
    abstract void addGear();
}
/* RefinedAbstraction - 1*/
class Car extends Vehicle{
    public Car(Gear gear){
        super(gear);
        // initialize various other Car components to make the car
    }
    public void addGear(){
        System.out.print("Car handles ");
        gear.handleGear();
    }
}
/* RefinedAbstraction - 2 */
class Truck extends Vehicle{
    public Truck(Gear gear){
        super(gear);
        // initialize various other Truck components to make the car
    }
    public void addGear(){
        System.out.print("Truck handles " );
        gear.handleGear();
    }
}
/* Client program */
public class BridgeDemo {    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Gear gear = new ManualGear();
        Vehicle vehicle = new Car(gear);
        vehicle.addGear();

        gear = new AutoGear();
        vehicle = new Car(gear);
        vehicle.addGear();

        gear = new ManualGear();
        vehicle = new Truck(gear);
        vehicle.addGear();

        gear = new AutoGear();
        vehicle = new Truck(gear);
        vehicle.addGear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a good design, a `Gear` should not care about outer enviroment. Thus, it should act regardless on which `Vehicle` it installed.

You could write something like

```
class SportCar extens Car {
  public SportCar (Gear gear){
    if (gear instanceof SportCarGear) {
      super(gear);
    } else {
      super(new SportCarGear());
      // throwing an exception is even worse
    }
}
```

but it **totally wrong** and violates too many things:

- expectations from user: `Car bolid = new SportCar(new TruckGear());` will not act as expected. One could say this violate Liskov principle but I'm not sure it's applicable
- higher coupling: now `SportCar` 'knows' about particular implementation of `Gear`
- if you have `CarGear`, `TruckGear` and so on, you have different design than *Bridge* offers

---

You use Bridge to make implementations of `Vehicle` and `Gear` independent. In that case any expectation that `Gear` should acts different for different implementations of `Vehicle` is ... very strange.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i undestand what kind of problem bridge pattern try to solve.Article John Sonmez about bridge pattern which i found here  https://simpleprogrammer.com/2015/06/08/design-patterns-simplified-the-bridge-pattern/ explains very well the pattern.